# Mysql, similar topics

Tags: mysql, tags, similarity

Hy guys!

I have 3 tables:

```
topics
(id*, title, body) 

tags
(id*,name)

topic_tags
(topic_id,tag_id)
```

Every topic has some tags. I want to find the "most related" topics to another one, based just on tags (and not based on the title and body of the topics).

If more common tags 2 topics have, they are more related. I want to order the results somehow by similarity (= number of common tags).

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  tr.*
FROM    topic t
JOIN    topic_tag tt
ON      tt.topic_id = t.id
JOIN    topic_tag ttr
ON      ttr.tag_id = tt.tag_id
JOIN    topic tr
ON      tr.id = ttr.topic_id
WHERE   t.id = $topicid
GROUP BY
        tr.id
ORDER BY
        COUNT(*) DESC
```